# Showing a picture in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, pycharm

I'm trying to show a figure, in PyCharm, that is in my working directory, but it either doesn't work or only works with this code:

```
img = mpimg.imread('Figure_1.png')
plt.imshow(img)
plt.show()
```

with this result:
[image: 1]]

I just want the picture as it is, not inside another figure. This is the original picture for reference:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some quick workarounds: to remove the axes, do `plt.axes('off')`. To make the picture fit the frame, set the aspect ratio to `'auto'` and create a figure with the same aspect ratio as your original image (i'd say it's roughly 4:1?). Use `tight_layout`to make sure all of your image is visible. I don't know if that's the official way, but that's how i do it, and it kinda works ;-)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg

img = mpimg.imread('Figure_1.png')
f, a = plt.subplots(figsize=(16, 4))
plt.tight_layout()
plt.axis('off')
a.imshow(img)
plt.show()
```

[image: Output]

Comment: right! sorry, i missed that when copying from my IDE.  Glad i could help!